# Adding Am/Pm to timestamp

Tags: angularjs, date, timestamp

I have a class which contains date among many other attributes:

```
Class example {
   Date lastUpdate;
}
```

So everytime there is change  I update the lastUpdate by

```
lastUpdate = new Date();
```

to get the new time stamp. In the database it gets updated correctly as `02-OCT-14 12.20.35.559000000 PM`. However when I try to display it on the UI using angular JS by calling `example.lastUpdate` it only displays `10/02/2014 12:20:35`. I need to know whether it was AM or PM how do I add that ?

Comment: Take a look at momentjs. It's an awesome lib for working with dates in JS. Format is the function you want to read up on.

Comment: wouldnt format in angular Js for date work ?

Answer (score 1):

you can create and use Angular your own angular filter for this, let's call it AMPMDateFormat and you can use this way {{ example.lastUpdate | AMPMDateFormat }} to display de AM or PM value next the current displayed value.

```
var app = angular.module('your-app', []);

app.filter("AMPMDateFormat", function () {
    return function(input) {

        //here you can use [Moment.js][1] 
        return moment(input).format();

        //or you can parse the input value by yourself
        //something like this  

        var parts = input.split(' ');

        var datePart = parts[0];

        var timeParts = parts[1].split(':');

        var hours = parseInt(timeParts[0]);

        var meridian = (hours < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";

        if (hours == 0) hours = 12;

        if (hours > 12) hours -= 12;

        return datePart + ", " + hours + ":" + timeParts[1] + " " + meridian;

    }
});
```

Hope this helps. 
!Important. Please, in the code all depends on the format of the input value. I'm assuming that the input format will always be "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" just like you said that is the way that it's currently displayed. If the format is other this code doesn't works! But the idea still working.

Comment: just reliased this does add AM/PM but incorrect. Its PM now adds AM instead

Comment: I am confused how could you decide if its AM/Pm by looking at 10:20:53 ? it could be any right

Comment: I decide by looking 10:20:53 that it's 'AM', 'PM' will be if I see 22:20:53. I decide this because my input must have military time format or 24-hour clock. If you have 12-hour clock you must have the AM/PM info attached to your input, if not, there's no way to know if it's AM or PM

Answer (score 1):

Angularjs allows you to format your date in the UI. See this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) for more information.

Therefore, you don't really need a function to do this. You could format this in your HTML.

**Example Controller snippet:**

```
angular
  .module("myApp")
  .controller('MyController',
    [ '$scope', function($scope) {

      $scope.myDate = new Date();      
    }]
  );
```

**Example UI snippet:**

```
<p>{{myDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a'}}</p>
```

In the above, `myDate` is a Date in the Controller that will display in the HTML in the format given. **The `a` portion is the AM/PM marker.** Thus, the value would, for example, look like this: `2014-10-07 10:10:02 AM`.

Comment: I dont want to update the date in the controller. i already have the date which has been updated  just to print it with the  AM/PM

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Are you trying to display the date anywhere?

Comment: Do you have more code (i.e., can you put code snippets in your post or a jsfiddle or plunker)? Where and how are you getting your date and displaying it in your ui? This makes a difference in how you can use angularjs to format it.